# What's the hacker script Syrian Shell doing?

Tags: php, exploit

Doing a site fix after a file was uploaded through an exploit. After examining the file, discovered a script named "Syrian Shell".

I found a version of it on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=MWRJYFyZ

Does anyone know it's core purpose? And how deep it can exploit the system?

I need to clean this particular server so if anyone has experience with it I appreciate your help. Thanks.

### Update

For all the weird kiddie hackers who are requesting to see the script, this paste is updated:

http://pastebin.com/kiqz88ce

Comment: just delete it. and plug what ever hole was used to upload it.

Comment: Looks to me like a script kiddie file for finding holes in your server to exploit (and possibly exploiting them, didn't look to in depth).

Comment: Why the hell is this a private release under the GPL license? It doesn't make sense. D:

Comment: script kiddies are never to bright (or they would have real jobs)

Comment: The link does not work any longer. That is not constructive. I vote to close the question unless you add the script again you ask about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your box is compromised, format it, and patch whatever security vulnerability was used in the first place. If you're crying about formatting it, then you clearly don't have a good server provisioning procedure in place. Next time, use standardized (automated) configurations and a configuration management system, like Puppet. Recreating a box doesn't take me personally more than a few keystrokes due to the kickstart configurations and our configuration management server.

Comment: I dont get why some people want to try and recover from this :-)

Comment: @Adrian, I agree that it's definitely work to set up, but a good disaster recovery procedure is essential to the longevity of any system. Usually better to bite the bullet upfront, IMHO.

Comment: Agree - I've had boxes I managed hacked and 'tried' to fix them - and there are back in within 24hr. Once comprised you cannot trust anything (had things like top/netstat replaced to hide the intrusion) I just hope Dustin doesnt work for my bank :-)

Comment: @Adrian don't worry I don't work for your bank this is a friend's website and server ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the first half of it, the script appears to be diagnostic.

The upside is it doesn't appear to directly harm the server or any data.  The downside is, if they understand the data it produces; they will know your server better than you.  That includes security weaknesses.

It's powered by POST parameters, which tell it what information to output.  A lot of it works in `if-else-if` blocks, which means only a few can be done at a time.  Check your server requests that involve that file and see what information they're requesting.

### EDIT:

I spoke too soon.  I scrolled down a little further and there are some offensive functions.  I think checking the server logs is even more important now.

Answer (score 0):

If your box was comprised - format it and reinstall. You will never know the depth of the penetration of your box. They logged in and installed software - you could be massively compromised.

Comment: The shell is not installable software!  It's just a small PHP script.

Comment: Generally through an upload of some sort.  Look up RFI. (Remote File Inclusion)

A lot of picture uploading scripts are vulnerable.

Comment: Right - so you guarantee that's all they did?

Comment: I didn't mention them doing anything, I just said you don't install a shell.  It's one simple PHP script with no dependencies.  And if safe mode was on, the shell is pretty much useless. Formatting would be overkill.

Comment: I am sorry - you have a machine that is compromised in unknown circumstance and you think formatting is overkill - who do you work for? Sony Playstation network by chance?

Comment: I don't think your attitude is needed.

Delete the shell, and the box is not compromised.  Do you have a working knowledge of PHP?